# Getting the Posts' permalinks from XLMRPC

Tags: permalinks, get-posts, xml-rpc

I'm new to WP and I must fetch pages/posts from a blog in another subdomain.
I'm using ZF to do this. I've recently found out the `getPages` doesn't get me what I want (posts; duh!). I didn't see any "getPosts" rpc methods for WP, so I've tried `blogger.getRecentPosts`. That's better, but now I don't have the permalinks. It would've been nice for it to return the same values as `getPages` does (title, permalink etc.).

I'm considering modifying (through filters, ofc) the WP's RPC server to return pages and all the relevant information, but, for now..
Is there a RPC method for WP to get Posts and their permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the metaWeblog api instead:  "metaWeblog.getRecentPosts".

This includes the permalink information.

See here:

http://mindsharestrategy.com/2010/wp-xmlrpc-metaweblog/